# Fabric: Answers: purchase flow tracking of `success` bool doesn't work as expected

Tags: ios, google-fabric

I'm tracking purchase-related events in an iOS app with Answers (part of Fabric). The Answers docs for [purchase flow tracking](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/answers/answers-events.html#purchase) are very straightforward:

```
Answers.logPurchaseWithPrice(13.50,
                  currency: "USD",
                  success: true,
                  itemName: "Answers Shirt",
                  itemType: "Apparel",
                  itemId: "sku-350",
                  customAttributes: nil)
```

The `success` bool is documented as:

> When a Purchase Event has the success attribute set to NO (Objective-C) or false (Swift), it is excluded from revenue charts but included in all other charts and calculations.

I've submitted one full flow of events, through Add Cart, Start Checkout, and Purchase, and for Purchase (`logPurchase…`) I set `success` to `false`, because I took the cancellation route, rather than completing the payment.

However, when I look at Answers' Purchase Funnel, I see a 100% purchase success rate:

[image]

That's not quite right! What's the proper Answers tracking call for a user tapping Cancel in my Purchase flow? It doesn't seem to be `logPurchaseWithPrice(… success: false…`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. Definitely understand the confusion on this, but will aim to clarify it.

If a user hits the event on each step of the funnel, then it would be considered a success regardless of the success attribute. The funnels are intended to function as a what % of your users hit the event triggers that were set within the app to send the data to Answers. If a user hits cancel, then you shouldn't trigger the logPurchase event. I recommend setting the event after the purchase has been confirmed - so on a successful tap or trigger of the final purchase button.

As you mentioned from the documentation, the success attribute only affects the revenue chart and the funnel does not take it into consideration.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! I was hesitant to remove the call to `logPurchase` for cancelled/failed purchases.